# Looping over an R function

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, genome, vcf-variant-call-format

I have a function in R which receives a .vcf file and parses it.

For instance

```
x <- "file1.vcf"

file1.parsed <- parse_vcf_alt1(x)
```

I have 177 .vcf files in a folder.

They look like this file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lcdmk57sy3dxexp/file1.vcf?dl=0

I want to feed each of these .vcf files, one by one, into the `parse_vcf_alt1` function and obtain a parsed file from that.

Manually doing this is a pain.

How can I automate this in R?

This code gives output

```
lapply(dir(), function(f) { if grep('vcf', f) { parse_vcf_alt1(f) }})
```

but I don't know how to save or write output for each parsed vcf separately with its own name.

```
> dput(frame)

 structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame") >
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!, Please, is it possible to see a glimpse of your data in `file1.vcf`? Taht help us to help you and make the problem reproducible.

Comment: Thank you this is link to one of my files https://www.dropbox.com/s/lcdmk57sy3dxexp/file1.vcf?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
frame <- data.frame()
lapply(dir(), function(f) { if(grep('vcs', f)) { frame[f] <- parse_vcf_alt1(f) }})
write.csv(frame, 'filename.csv')
```

dir returns the list of files, grep checks their name and calls parse_vcf if it matches. frame[f] assigns it to a column of the data frame, after which it can be retrieved using, say, frame$vcs.hd1.vcf or whatever the filename happens to be. Finally, write.csv will write your results to filename.csv in the current directory.

Comment: Sorry says > lapply(getwd(), function(f) { if grep('vcf', f) { parse_vcf_alt1(f) }})
Error: unexpected symbol in "lapply(getwd(), function(f) { if grep

Comment: Use dir, not getwd?

Comment: Thank you but I don't know where the output goes. I have posted the results. How we can write or save the output for each file separately somewhere with their name to be able to locate that?

Comment: Thank you I edited that, please help me if possible because after parsing each file I need them separately to be saved to written somewhere

Comment: Thank you that pushed each file which a list, how I can write that to separate file? for instance results[1] is for first file and results[2] for the second one but I don't know how to separate them and writing them as a .csv or table independently

Comment: Please see my edit. 

At this point, should you require further help, accept this answer, put up another question and point me to it.

Comment: Thank you I accepted the answer but the written .csv is empty :(. Actually each list is one file which I need them to be written separately to an independent files by their names

Comment: Can you dput(frame) then?

Comment: Thank you > dput(frame)
structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame")
>

Comment: No, add the dput output to your question

Comment: Sorry what you mean?

Comment: Edit your question and add the dput(frame) output there.